# Dynamically access object using variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to access an object using a dynamic name. Is this possible?

```
const something = { bar: "Foobar!" };
const objectName = 'something';
const propertyName = 'bar';

[objectName][propertyName]; // The idea is to access something.bar, getting "Foobar!"
```

edit : I am trying to use a variable to access the object itself, not its properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Updated your question to make propertyName relevant.

Comment: @raina77ow thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the variables you declare in the browser are properties of the `window` object so you could actually use this.

```
var something = { bar: 'Foobar!' };
var objectName = 'something';
var propertyName = 'bar';

window[objectName][propertyName];
```

But this only works when you declare variables with `var`. It doesn't work for `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one [deceptively simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) way to do it:

```
eval(objectName)[propertyName];
```

... which is obviously a **really bad** idea if you ever can lose the full control over what's stored in `objectName` variable (and just a bad idea otherwise, as `eval` code won't be optimized and controlled by your spellchecking IDE magic, for example).

Far better idea is to turn your `something` (and any other name you want to query) into a property of an object itself. For example:

```
const state = {
  something: {
    foo: 'Foobar'
  }
};
```

... and later access it with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
console.log(state[objectName][propertyName]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this script

```
    var something = { bar: "Foobar!" };
    var objectName = 'something';
    var propertyName = 'bar';

    console.log(eval(objectName)[propertyName]);
```